# Reorder histograms on a ridgeline plot

Tags: python, plot, ridgeline-plot

I am trying to construct a ridgeline plot using joypy. I have a dataframe with 2 columns: one of the columns represents the names of the samples and the other the values to be plotted:

`sampleName     value`

`C             -11`

`C             -12`

`C             -14`

`A             -10`

`A             -8`

`B             -6`

`B             -7`

Upon plotting the values above with the following command:

`import joypy`

`joypy.joyplot(data = data_to_plot, by = 'sampleName', column = ["value"], legend = True)`

I get this plot, which is ordered (as it looks like) by the values in increasing order (from more negative to less negative in the case of this data).

[image: plot]

Is there a way to specify the ordering, e.g. by the sample names, and input one's own order of plotting, instead of `C->A->B`, `A->B->C`?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do the same thing, and it turns out sorting your data does the trick.

```
data_to_plot = data_to_plot.sort_values('sampleName', ascending = False)
```